# Build errors when installing via setup.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm running Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have an issue where whenever I install a package via `python setup.py install`, if there is any building involved the process errors. This happens even though I have all the necessary libraries installed for each package such as `python-dev`, `libfreetype6-dev`, `build-essential`, etc. Yet, when I install using pip everything is fine. Any idea what could be happening here?

This happens with a number of packages, e.g. matplotlib, scipy, numpy, scikit-learn, etc.

Here is one such error. This is when installing in a virtualenv a package that installs matplotlib as a dependency.

```
Running matplotlib-1.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rzaewxbc/matplotlib-1.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-0rn9mt24
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.1]
                python: yes [3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)  [GCC
                        4.8.4]]
              platform: yes [linux]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.11.0]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                        it after matplotlib.]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.5.2]
                   png: yes [version 1.2.50]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

In file included from src/_path_wrapper.cpp:3:0:
src/_path.h: In function ‘PyObject* Py_is_sorted(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
src/_path.h:1215:17: warning: ‘last_value’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
                 if (current_value < last_value) {
                 ^
src/_path.h:1193:11: note: ‘last_value’ was declared here
         T last_value;
           ^
extern/qhull/poly.c: In function ‘qh_delfacet’:
extern/qhull/poly.c:248:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp; /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^
extern/qhull/poly.c: In function ‘qh_makenew_nonsimplicial’:
extern/qhull/poly.c:564:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp; /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^
extern/qhull/poly.c: In function ‘qh_newfacet’:
extern/qhull/poly.c:981:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp; /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^
extern/qhull/poly.c: In function ‘qh_newridge’:
extern/qhull/poly.c:1014:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp;   /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^
extern/qhull/geom.c: In function ‘qh_projectpoint’:
extern/qhull/geom.c:897:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp; /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^
extern/qhull/geom.c: In function ‘qh_setfacetplane’:
extern/qhull/geom.c:935:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp; /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^
extern/qhull/poly2.c: In function ‘qh_delridge’:
extern/qhull/poly2.c:1076:10: warning: variable ‘freelistp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   void **freelistp; /* used !qh_NOmem */
          ^

             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.10]
                 latex: no
               pdftops: yes [version 0.24.5]

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/matplotlib/_version.py
set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/matplotlib/_version.py to '1.5.1'
creating /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
Extracting matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg to /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding matplotlib 1.5.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
Searching for tinydb>=2.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/tinydb/
Best match: tinydb 3.2.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/6c/91/a6959e7199bd6a97521be2922369d65673c89511a3ce662c865b9adbec3a/tinydb-3.2.0.zip#md5=8584ac822a97cd77b0d68641025959c8
Processing tinydb-3.2.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-d384vlmr/tinydb-3.2.0/setup.cfg
Running tinydb-3.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-d384vlmr/tinydb-3.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-cjrbtyb_
Moving tinydb-3.2.0-py3.4.egg to /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding tinydb 3.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinydb-3.2.0-py3.4.egg
Searching for structlog>=15.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/structlog/
Best match: structlog 16.0.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/6e/8e/7be23d5ef287113264b93676ab67f895f28b5f795d91a9a45ba3f4daeeab/structlog-16.0.0.tar.gz#md5=59ac00a23b966c6d63ad85c26f454ea9
Processing structlog-16.0.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-bsj7_ze6/structlog-16.0.0/setup.cfg
Running structlog-16.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-bsj7_ze6/structlog-16.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-l1soaiok
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
creating /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/structlog-16.0.0-py3.4.egg
Extracting structlog-16.0.0-py3.4.egg to /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding structlog 16.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/structlog-16.0.0-py3.4.egg
Searching for pyyaml>=3.11
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyyaml/
Best match: PyYAML 3.11
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/75/5e/b84feba55e20f8da46ead76f14a3943c8cb722d40360702b2365b91dec00/PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz#md5=f50e08ef0fe55178479d3a618efe21db
Processing PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-l68tdp1v/PyYAML-3.11/setup.cfg
Running PyYAML-3.11/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-l68tdp1v/PyYAML-3.11/egg-dist-tmp-tgsfkksl
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/check_libyaml.c:2:18: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
 #include <yaml.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.

libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
(if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
 specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
 modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving PyYAML-3.11-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg to /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding PyYAML 3.11 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyYAML-3.11-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
Searching for euclid>=0.01
Best match: euclid 0.1
Downloading https://github.com/robclewley/pyeuclid/tarball/master#egg=euclid-0.01
Processing master
Writing /tmp/easy_install-sji052j6/robclewley-pyeuclid-48c7343/setup.cfg
Running robclewley-pyeuclid-48c7343/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-sji052j6/robclewley-pyeuclid-48c7343/egg-dist-tmp-vcsee6i1
/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:285: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.01' to '0.1'
  normalized_version,
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving euclid-0.1-py3.4.egg to /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding euclid 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/euclid-0.1-py3.4.egg
Searching for descartes>=1.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/descartes/
Best match: descartes 1.0.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/52/65/6078084b6b84b8c87730f9ebf825fbcd7f1ba7bf383fbb6f0a8a6d2419af/descartes-1.0.2.tar.gz#md5=2af859c63f73ef852c691f46a06e5938
Processing descartes-1.0.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-dnpe4t7m/descartes-1.0.2/setup.cfg
Running descartes-1.0.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-dnpe4t7m/descartes-1.0.2/egg-dist-tmp-hki7dbdg
creating /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/descartes-1.0.2-py3.4.egg
Extracting descartes-1.0.2-py3.4.egg to /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Adding descartes 1.0.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/descartes-1.0.2-py3.4.egg
Searching for shapely>=1.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/shapely/
Best match: Shapely 1.5.15
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/dc/44/84893410afc713e44a82a8f900de3ea63a80fa460beb3f9a9fed2ded0140/Shapely-1.5.15.tar.gz#md5=c2e06fb89cdbd959b89ae69794ede3c0
Processing Shapely-1.5.15.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-79agryb8/Shapely-1.5.15/setup.cfg
Running Shapely-1.5.15/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-79agryb8/Shapely-1.5.15/egg-dist-tmp-ewu7r0i6
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:1051:28: warning: ‘__pyx_f_7shapely_8speedups_9_speedups_get_geos_context_handle’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static GEOSContextHandle_t __pyx_f_7shapely_8speedups_9_speedups_get_geos_context_handle(void) {
                            ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:1137:30: warning: ‘__pyx_f_7shapely_8speedups_9_speedups_geos_from_prepared’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static GEOSPreparedGeometry *__pyx_f_7shapely_8speedups_9_speedups_geos_from_prepared(PyObject *__pyx_v_shapely_geom) {
                              ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_7shapely_8speedups_9_speedups_affine_transform.isra.38’:
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:6797:39: warning: ‘__pyx_v_the_geom_t’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t(((uintptr_t)__pyx_v_the_geom_t)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 489; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                       ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:5963:19: warning: ‘__pyx_v_zoff’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       __pyx_v_z_t = ((((__pyx_v_g * __pyx_v_x) + (__pyx_v_h * __pyx_v_y)) + (__pyx_v_i * __pyx_v_z)) + __pyx_v_zoff);
                   ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:6034:10: note: ‘__pyx_v_zoff’ was declared here
   double __pyx_v_zoff;
          ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:5963:88: warning: ‘__pyx_v_i’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       __pyx_v_z_t = ((((__pyx_v_g * __pyx_v_x) + (__pyx_v_h * __pyx_v_y)) + (__pyx_v_i * __pyx_v_z)) + __pyx_v_zoff);
                                                                                        ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:6031:10: note: ‘__pyx_v_i’ was declared here
   double __pyx_v_i;
          ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:5963:61: warning: ‘__pyx_v_h’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       __pyx_v_z_t = ((((__pyx_v_g * __pyx_v_x) + (__pyx_v_h * __pyx_v_y)) + (__pyx_v_i * __pyx_v_z)) + __pyx_v_zoff);
                                                             ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:6030:10: note: ‘__pyx_v_h’ was declared here
   double __pyx_v_h;
          ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:5963:35: warning: ‘__pyx_v_g’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       __pyx_v_z_t = ((((__pyx_v_g * __pyx_v_x) + (__pyx_v_h * __pyx_v_y)) + (__pyx_v_i * __pyx_v_z)) + __pyx_v_zoff);
                                   ^
shapely/speedups/_speedups.c:6029:10: note: ‘__pyx_v_g’ was declared here
   double __pyx_v_g;
          ^
warning: no library file corresponding to '/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include' found (skipping)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-79agryb8/Shapely-1.5.15/setup.py", line 295, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 10, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-79agryb8/Shapely-1.5.15/setup.py", line 211, in run
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 164, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 171, in build_extensions
    ext.sources = self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 324, in cython_sources
    full_module_name=module_name)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 682, in compile
    return compile_single(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 635, in compile_single
    return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 452, in run_pipeline
    from . import Pipeline
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .Visitor import CythonTransform
  File "Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py", line 15, in init Cython.Compiler.Visitor (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.c:19160)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4355, in <module>
    class SliceIndexNode(ExprNode):
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4507, in SliceIndexNode
    "SliceObject", "ObjectHandling.c", context={'access': 'Get'})
  File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 286, in Cython.Compiler.Code.UtilityCodeBase.load (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c:9266)
  File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 528, in Cython.Compiler.Code.TempitaUtilityCode.__init__ (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c:15652)
  File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 520, in Cython.Compiler.Code.sub_tempita (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c:15377)
SystemError: ../Objects/moduleobject.c:205: bad argument to internal function

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 69, in <module>
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 117, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 391, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 621, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 672, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 717, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 640, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 670, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 850, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1064, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-79agryb8/Shapely-1.5.15/setup.py", line 295, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 10, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-79agryb8/Shapely-1.5.15/setup.py", line 211, in run
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 164, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 171, in build_extensions
    ext.sources = self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 324, in cython_sources
    full_module_name=module_name)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 682, in compile
    return compile_single(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 635, in compile_single
    return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 452, in run_pipeline
    from . import Pipeline
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .Visitor import CythonTransform
  File "Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py", line 15, in init Cython.Compiler.Visitor (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.c:19160)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4355, in <module>
    class SliceIndexNode(ExprNode):
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/gsoc/scikit-learn/crusty/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4507, in SliceIndexNode
    "SliceObject", "ObjectHandling.c", context={'access': 'Get'})
  File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 286, in Cython.Compiler.Code.UtilityCodeBase.load (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c:9266)
  File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 528, in Cython.Compiler.Code.TempitaUtilityCode.__init__ (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c:15652)
  File "Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 520, in Cython.Compiler.Code.sub_tempita (/tmp/pip-build-tji983vs/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c:15377)
SystemError: ../Objects/moduleobject.c:205: bad argument to internal function
```

Comment: Can you show any of the errors during setup.py execution

Comment: Yes, I will try running again and edit my answer.

Comment: @RSingh I have updated the question, but I had to cut out a bit of the build output because it was too long.